# How to give Domain Name to IPs in an Intranet Network

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2003, php

I Know this is a Common topic here but I'm still confused.
I have a Windows Server 2003 DHCP/App Server Machine with DNS configured. The Clients are Lubuntu 12.04 Systems.
I want to host my PHP Application on the Intranet by a domain name. But Im not sure how to do that. I know about Hosts File thing but I cant Daily change the Host File as the systems might change.
My Server's Static IP is 10.12.16.1 subnet 255.0.0.0 DNS name: gn-lrr.intranet
When I put my SERVER NAME (i.e gn-lrr-server) name on the address bar of FF the Site opens, will it work on other pcs the same way?.

Please Give a detailed instructions. Regards!

Answer (score 1):

The hostname of your server, `gn-lrr-server` is a local name in your network. It won't work from outside of your network without a VPN connection. But as long as the application is only used internally, this hostname will work on all machines that use your Windows Server 2003 as their DNS server (which they likely all do). If you have machines in your network that use another DNS server than your own server, you should alter their hosts file by adding this line:

```
10.12.16.1    gn-lrr-server
```

That way, they will resolve that name to the given IP address, no matter what DNS server they use.

Comment: thanks... they use my dns server only so it will work normally right?
That is no extra settings required?

Comment: plus how can i make gn-librr-server/lms to lms.gn-librr-server via DNS?

Comment: @DragoTech.Innovations Yes, as long as they use your DNS, the name will always resolve to the correct IP address. The subdomain must be added in your DNS configuration, along with the subdomain configuration on your web server (probably IIS). Then under the `lms` directory of your main domain, add a file that redirects them to your subdomain. It's quite a few steps, so you might want to add this as a new question if the above is not sufficient.

Comment: Thank you... Last Night the client PCs were not resolving gn-lrr-server to the desired page... instead they started a google search... why did that occur?
Sorry for any typos.. my hands are freezing... ;)

Comment: They specifically need to use either a `http://` prefix or a `.intranet` suffix to avoid starting a search. The http prefix should work best. A bookmark might also help :)

Comment: Thanks Alot! Will Try that at night and confirm results! :D

Comment: BUMP...
adding http:// or .intranet doesnt work on neither on linux machines or windows machines...

Comment: anyone? please help...